# java.util.InputMismatchException is Occuring

Tags: java

I am trying to input value in this code, but getting a

> java.util.InputMismatchException

I've tried it many times but still not getting the correct one. (It's Compiling Fine)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    String name;
    int rollno;

    Test(String x, int y) {
        this.name = x;
        this.rollno = y;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Test[] t = new Test[2];

        for(int i = 0; i<2 ;i++) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            t[i] = new Test(s,x);
        }

        for(int j = 0 ; j<2 ; j++) {
            System.out.println(t[j].name + "----" + t[j].rollno);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
java Test
vinod
24
kumar
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Test.main(test4.java:22)
```

Comment: You need another `sc.nextLine()` after the `sc.nextInt()`, otherwise the scanner stays on the end of the line of the 24, then at the next iteration the `String s` will be the empty end of line and the `sc.nextInt()` will fail with the error you're getting when trying to parse `kumar` as an int.

Comment: but it will increase the length of the code, is there any efficient or small way to do this stuff?

Comment: @vinodkumar with your nextInt(), you only read the int. but you also press enter (which produces a "\n"). this will add 1 line of code, but at least it'll work

Comment: Is your harddrive so full that one more line of code would be a problem? There is no method that would read a token from an `InputStream`, parse it as an `int` and discard the following linefeed, sorry. You could do `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())`, but that would be worse than what I initially proposed in multiple ways.

Comment: Ok I'll try it, thank you.

Comment: You have one empty line and every curly brace started from new line what already makes your code look longer, do you really think that extra line of necessary functionality can spoil everything?

Comment: Its working, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = sc.nextLine();
int x = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();  //  <-- switch to the next line after input int value
t[i] = new Test(s, x);
```

---

Full code could be look like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for (Test test : readData(2))
        System.out.println(test.name + " ---- " + test.rollno);
}

private static Test[] readData(int total) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        Test[] data = new Test[total];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++, scan.nextLine())
            data[i] = new Test(scan.nextLine(), scan.nextInt());

        return data;
    }
}
```